# PowerShell Ctrl+L not working as expected, how to debug?

Tags: windows, powershell

Previously, my PowerShell client would clear all text upon pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>, effectively executing a `clear`/`cls`.

Seemingly out of the blue <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> clears the terminal but upon typing, all the text comes back to fill the prompt.

How may I go about debugging this issue? Using "Enable legacy console" fixes it, but I'd rather use latest. I could always override the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> chord but I'd rather try and determine how it got to this state in the first place.

Comment: Have you checked your `PSReadLine` settings haven't changed?  That's a module always running (assuming powershell v5) and handles the events regarding key combos.

Comment: You can validate with this command: `Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler -Bound | ? Function -eq ClearScreen` or `? Key -eq Ctrl+l`

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 yes, the above yields `Ctrl+l` mapped to `ClearScreen`.

Comment: And you're just launching `powershell.exe`?  Not through another interpreter like cmder or otherwise?

Comment: That's correct.

Comment: 32 and 64 bit versions as well as running as admin yield the same problem.

Comment: Did you recently upgrade to Windows 10 release 1809? It looks like the problem may be related to that: see https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine/issues/841

Comment: The weirdest thing is I installed PowerShell 6 and have the same issue there...

Comment: Did you try using another version of PSReadLine (that is also a module)?